# variable from input name syntax mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to target a variable by the name of an input field using the following code and update the link, it works if I use `sample_variable = ();` rather than `b = (value);` so I assume it's a really obvious syntax problem.

```
<input id="my_input" type="text" name="sample_variable1">

sample_variable1 = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
sample_variable2 = "http://www.google.com";
sample_variable3 = "http://www.yahoo.com";

            $('#set3').find('input').focus(function(){
            var a = $(this).attr("id");
            var b = $(this).attr("name");


            $('#'+a).live('change',(function(){
                            var value = $(this).val();
                            b = (value);

                            })
                            );
            });
```

I'm trying to update the value (html link) of the variable to what was entered in the text input, but select the correct variable to update by using a corresponding input name. I'm doing it this way so I don't have to write out the same block of code for each var.

Thanks, Tom

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. What's supposed to be what? If you're looking for variable variables in Javascript: don't. Use arrays instead.

Comment: What `type` of `input` is that?

Comment: sorry, it's a text input. I have several variables and I'm trying to target the one corresponding to the input by making the name the same as the variable name. I'm very new to javascript!!

Comment: edited the question for clarity. How would I use an array in this instance deceze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to set the value of of the `sample_variable` according to the value of the name field of your selection, it's not easy. There are some tricks with eval, but still not a very good idea. You would be better off with an object's property:

```
var properties = {};
....
properties[b] = $(this).val();
```